# Service Fabric dynamic partitioning

Tags: azure-service-fabric

So I am doing some research into using Service Fabric for a very large application. One thing I need to have is a service that is partitioned by name, which seems fairly trivial at the application manifest level.

However, I really would like to be able to add and remove named partitions on the fly without having to republish the application.

Each partition represents our equivalent of a tenant, and we want to have a backend management app to add new tenants.

Each partition will be a long-running application that fires up a TCP server that uses a custom protocol, and I'll need to be able to query for the address by name from the cluster.

Is this possible with Service Fabric, and if so is there any documentation on this, or something I should be looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Each partition represents our equivalent of a tenant, and we want to have a backend management app to add new tenants.

You need to rethink your model. Partitioning is for distributing data so it accessible fast, for read and write. But within the same logical container.

If you want to do some multitenant in Service Fabric you can deploy an Application multiple times to the cluster.

From Visual Studio it seems you can only have one instance of an Application. This is because in the ApplicationManifest.xml there are DefaultServices defined. This is okay for developing on the local Service Fabric cluster. For production you might want to consider deploying the application with powershell, this will open up the possibility to deploy the same application multiple times with settings for each instance(like: tenant name, security, ... )

And not only Applications can be deployed multiple times, stateful/stateless services as well. So you could have one application and for each tenant you deploy a service of a certain type. Services are findable via the naming service inside Service Fabric, see the FabricClient class for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I can create the service instances using FabricClient as well so I don't need to mess with PowerShell on my backend. Looks like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change the partition count for an existing application. 
From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning/#plan-for-partitioning (emphasis mine):

> In rare cases, you may end up needing more partitions than you have initially chosen. As **you cannot change the partition count after the fact**, you would need to apply some advanced partition approaches, such as creating a new service instance of the same service type. You would also need to implement some client-side logic that routes the requests to the correct service instance, based on client-side knowledge that your client code must maintain.

You are encouraged to do up-front capacity planning to determine the maximum number of partitions you will need - and if you end up needing more, you'll need to implement some special client side handling to cope.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and ended up creating an instance of the service for each tenant. This is pretty easy to do and will scale to any number of tenants.